# MySQL database migration to WordPress

Tags: php, database, mysql, wpdb

I have a MySQL database established for a web application I have been working on in a non WordPress database. This database has many tables with pre-populated rows for foreign keys etc. which took a long while to input. I am trying to figure out how I can bring these tables into the WordPress database intact. Also I am wondering how when I have done this I could give the table names a prefix to denote them as separate to the WordPress core tables.

I have also created the processforms.php file where I have used the mysqli prepare and bind param method to prevent SQL injections, is there any benefit to recoding this using the $wpdb prepare method?

Any help you could offer with this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Anthony

Edit... I have now migrated the tables with new prefix using the PHPMyAdmin copy table function, any help on the other question regarding $wpdb would be appreciated. I am basically wondering if the $wpdb method gives any security advantages over the method I have used noted above.

Thanks

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From technical perspective `wpdb->prepare()` essentially trickles down to escaping variables with either (depending on configuration) [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

It's not inherently more or less secure than any other properly implemented escaping routine. It *is* closer to specifics of WP and configuration it is aware off.